# Django dynamic filtering by passing slug from template

Tags: django, url, view, filtering

So I've read this article on dynamic filtering in Django; [Dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Though I had something working I needed two similar views, one to show all different categories with their slug as parameter, and a second view to show all posts from all categories without a parameter.

How can I use a single ListView and pass an empty parameter from the template to show all posts from all categories in a list?

Or would this even be possible?

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),
  path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostbyCategoryListView.as_view(), name="category"),
]
```

## views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'index.html'

class PostbyCategoryListView(ListView):
  model = Post
  template_name = 'index.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    return Post.objects.filter(category=self.category)
```

## index.html

```
...
  <h6>Categories</h6>
  {% if category_list %}
    <ul>
      <li class="category-item">
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">All categories</a>
      </li>
      {% for category in category_list %}
        <li class="category-item">
          <a href="{% url 'category' category.slug %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% else %}
      <p>No categories</p>
  {% endif %}
...
```

## models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Post(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey('Category',default=1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="posts")
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  content = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: Done, also fixed the "get_list_or_404" on Post and changed it to "get_object_or_404" on Category